# Reduce multiple blocks of equal length that are arranged in a big vector Using CUDA

Tags: cuda, nvidia, gpgpu, thrust, reduction

I am looking for a fast way to reduce multiple blocks of equal length 
that are arranged as a big vector. 
I have N subarrays(contiguous elements) that are arranged in one big array. each sub array has a fixed size : k.
so the size of the whole array is : N*K

What I'm doing is to call the kernel N times. in each time it computes the reduction of the subarray as follow:
I will iterate over all the subarrays contained in the big vector :

```
    for(i=0;i<N;i++){
       thrust::device_vector< float > Vec(subarray, subarray+k);
       float sum = thrust::reduce(Vec.begin(), Vec.end(), (float)0, thrust::plus<float>());
       printf("sum %f\n",sum);
 }
```

for pure CUDA i will do it like this (pseudo code):

```
 for(i=0;i<N;i++){
        reduction_kernel(subarray)

         }
```

do you have another solution to perform the reduction of the contiguous subarrays in once? using pure CUDA or Thrust

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you're asking for is a segmented reduction.  This can be done in thrust using [`thrust::reduce_by_key`](https://thrust.github.io/doc/group__reductions.html#gad5623f203f9b3fdcab72481c3913f0e0)  In addition to your data vector of length N*K, we will need a "key" vector that defines each segment -- the segments don't have to be the same size, as long as the key vector differentiates segments like so:

```
data:  1 3 2 3 1 4 2 3 2 1 4 2 ...
keys:  0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 3 3 3 ...
seg:   0 0 0 1 1 1 2 2 2 3 3 3 ...
```

The keys delineate a new segment any time the key sequence changes (note that I have two separate segments in the above example that are delineated using the same key - thrust doesn't group such segments together but treats them separately because there are 1 or more intervening key values that are different).  You don't actually have this data, but for speed and efficiency, since your segments are of equal length, we can produce the necessary key sequence "on the fly" using a combination of thrust [fancy iterators](https://github.com/thrust/thrust/wiki/Quick-Start-Guide).

The fancy iterators will combine to:

1. produce a linear sequence 0 1 2 3 ... (via counting_iterator)
2. divide each member of the linear sequence by K, the segment length (via transform_iterator).  I'm using [thrust placeholder methodology](https://thrust.github.io/doc/namespaceplaceholders.html) here so I don't have to write a functor for the transform iterator.

This will produce the necessary segment-key sequence.

Here is a worked example:

```
$ cat t1282.cu
#include <thrust/reduce.h>
#include <thrust/device_vector.h>
#include <thrust/iterator/transform_iterator.h>
#include <thrust/iterator/counting_iterator.h>
#include <thrust/iterator/discard_iterator.h>
#include <thrust/copy.h>
#include <thrust/execution_policy.h>
#include <iostream>

const int N = 1000;  // sequences
const int K = 100;   // length of sequence
typedef int mytype;

using namespace thrust::placeholders;

int main(){

  thrust::device_vector<mytype> data(N*K, 1);
  thrust::device_vector<mytype> sums(N);
  thrust::reduce_by_key(thrust::device, thrust::make_transform_iterator(thrust::counting_iterator<int>(0), _1/K), thrust::make_transform_iterator(thrust::counting_iterator<int>(N*K), _1/K), data.begin(), thrust::discard_iterator<int>(), sums.begin());
  // just display the first 10 results
  thrust::copy_n(sums.begin(), 10, std::ostream_iterator<mytype>(std::cout, ","));
  std::cout << std::endl;
}

$ nvcc -arch=sm_35 -o t1282 t1282.cu
$ ./t1282
100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,
$
```

Comment: Thank you, Mr. Robert, for the worked example. I have just question: it is can be implemented using pure CUDA? based on the knowledge that I have right now I will use nested kernels it is a good idea?  or there is another optimal way. @Robert Crovella

Comment: Certainly its possible to implement it using pure CUDA..  Thrust uses pure CUDA when running on a GPU, and Thrust is open source.  I don't know if nested kernels is a good idea, since I haven't tried to implement using pure CUDA.

Comment: Do you any have an idea about how this will be implemented? Also Im thinking to launch 1000 kernels in the same time each one compute the reduction for the 100 sequence. @Robert Crovella. Also I'm wondering if you know some references that may help me to be more confortable with CUDA and parallelism. In fact parallelism it is not my field. Thank you in advance Mr. Robert

Comment: I assume you mean "how this would be implemented **in CUDA**" ? A general purpose segmented reduction is not something I would try to implement in CUDA - there are already library implementations e.g. in thrust and cub that are written by people who are much smarter than me.  This is generally a good practice in SW engineering anyway - don't reinvent the wheel.  But I think an example here would not be too hard to do if we make some simplifying assumptions.  What exactly are the values or ranges of values for `N` and `K` that you care about?

Comment: I think I will go until  N = 100.000 and the  K =  10.000.000 @Robert Crovella

Comment: So you have a vector of length 100000*10000000 ?  That won't fit in GPU memory for any current GPU.  For `int` or `float` quantities, that is approximately 4 Terabytes of data.  Are you working on a system with 4+ Terabytes of memory?  I will just assume the problem size is as big as GPU memory will hold.

Comment: Im working on Tesla K20C . if it can't fit I will reduce the size of the K and the N but i want using the max . In fact the idea is to start with  medium size and go further. that is the point. :s   @Robert Crovella

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/135901/discussion-between-alae-and-robert-crovella).

Comment: I've provided an answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42277338/computing-the-mean-of-2000-2d-arrays-with-cuda-c) to a question very similar to yours.  The code there can be used to solve exactly the case you describe, up to the limits of the memory of whatever GPU you are working on.

Comment: Thank you very much dear Mr. Rober @Rober Crovella  I will study the solution carefully.

Comment: Just to be sure of my information : in general we have limited number of threads per block for my GPU is 1024. and the number of threads per block must be a multiple of 32 which is the size of a wrap right ?@Robert Crovella

Comment: These are very basic questions which are answered in many questions here on the CUDA tag as well as in the [cuda programming guide](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#abstract).

Comment: Thank you very mush dear Mr. Robert @Robert Crovella