# Search Minimum/Maximum from n Arrays parallel in CUDA (Reduction Problem)

Tags: cuda, reduction

Is there a performant way in CUDA to get out of multiple arrays (which exist in different structures)
to find the maximum/minimum in parallel?  The structures are structured according to the Structure of Arrays format.

A simple idea would be to assign each array to a thread block, which is used to calculate the maximum/minimum using the parallel reduction approach. The problem here is the size of the shared memory, which is why I regard this approach as critical. 
An other approach is to calculate every Miminum/Maximum separetly for each Array. I think this is to slow.

```
    struct Cube {
     int* x;
     int* y;
     int* z;
     int size;
    };

    int main() {
     Cube* c1 = new Cube(); //c1 includes 100 Cubes (because of SOA)
     c1-> x = new int[100];
     c1-> y = new int[100];
     c1 -> z = new int[100];

     Cube* c2 = new Cube();
     c2-> x = new int[1047];
     c2-> y = new int[1047];
     c2 -> z = new int[1047];

     Cube* c3 = new Cube();
     c3-> x = new int[5000];
     c3-> y = new int[5000];
     c3 -> z = new int[5000];

    //My goal now is to find the smallest/largest x dimension of all cubes in c1, c2, ..., and cn, 
    //with one Kernel launch. 
    //So the smallest/largest x in c1, the smallest/largest x in c2 etc..



    }
```

Does anyone know an efficient approach? Thanks.

Comment: There won't be anything convenient or efficient about working with the 3 (or `n`) different `Cube` arrays if they are all of different lengths.  In that case for efficiency you would be better off concatenating them all and doing a segmented min/max reduction, eg. `thrust::reduce_by_key`, which could do it all in a minimum number of  kernel launches under the hood.

Comment: Thanks for the answer
I have now googled 3 hours to find out how to use the thrust::reduce_by_key adequately here. Unfortunately, I didn't find out how to create an iterator that gives me the keys. Could you show me how this works with the 3 arrays example?

Comment: The first step would be to concatenate the arrays.  I bet you can do that.  The next step is to create a suitably constructed key array that delineates the segments.  For that and the remainder, [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42260493/reduce-multiple-blocks-of-equal-length-that-are-arranged-in-a-big-vector-using-c) should give much of the information you need to complete the work.  Yes, I understand that refers to equal-length segments, but the construction of a flag array for unequal length segments shouldn't be difficult.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer.
I looked at the example and tried to understand it. I couldn't quite understand how I could include different K values (representing the different array lengths) in this example. 
I would be very happy if you could help me again.

Answer (score 1):

> A simple idea would be to assign each array to a thread block, which is used to calculate the maximum/minimum using the parallel reduction approach. The problem here is the size of the shared memory, which is why I regard this approach as critical.

There is no problem with shared memory size.  You may wish to review Mark Harris' [canonical parallel reduction tutorial](https://developer.download.nvidia.com/assets/cuda/files/reduction.pdf) and look at the later methods to understand how we can use a loop to populate shared memory, reducing values into shared memory as we go.  Once the input loop is completed, then we begin the block-sweep phase of the reduction.  This doesn't impose any special requirements on the shared memory per block.

Here's a worked example demonstrating both a `thrust::reduce_by_key` method (single call) and a CUDA block-segmented method (single kernel call):

```
$ cat t1535.cu
#include <iostream>
#include <thrust/reduce.h>
#include <thrust/copy.h>
#include <thrust/device_vector.h>
#include <thrust/host_vector.h>
#include <thrust/iterator/constant_iterator.h>
#include <thrust/iterator/discard_iterator.h>
#include <thrust/iterator/zip_iterator.h>
#include <thrust/functional.h>
#include <cstdlib>
#define IMAX(x,y) (x>y)?x:y
#define IMIN(x,y) (x<y)?x:y
typedef int dtype;
const int ncubes = 3;
struct Cube {
    dtype* x;
    dtype* y;
    dtype* z;
    int size;
};

struct my_f
{
  template <typename T1, typename T2>
  __host__ __device__
  thrust::tuple<dtype,dtype> operator()(T1 t1, T2 t2){
    thrust::tuple<dtype,dtype> r;
    thrust::get<0>(r) = IMAX(thrust::get<0>(t1),thrust::get<0>(t2));
    thrust::get<1>(r) = IMIN(thrust::get<1>(t1),thrust::get<1>(t2));
    return r;
    }
};
const int MIN = -1;
const int MAX = 0x7FFFFFFF;
const int BS = 512;
template <typename T>
__global__ void block_segmented_minmax_reduce(const T * __restrict__ in, T * __restrict__ max, T * __restrict__ min, const size_t * __restrict__ slen){

  __shared__ T smax[BS];
  __shared__ T smin[BS];
  size_t my_seg_start = slen[blockIdx.x];
  size_t my_seg_size = slen[blockIdx.x+1] - my_seg_start;
  smax[threadIdx.x] = MIN;
  smin[threadIdx.x] = MAX;
  for (size_t idx = my_seg_start+threadIdx.x; idx < my_seg_size; idx += BS){
    T my_val = in[idx];
    smax[threadIdx.x] = IMAX(my_val, smax[threadIdx.x]);
    smin[threadIdx.x] = IMIN(my_val, smin[threadIdx.x]);}
  for (int s = BS>>1; s > 0; s>>=1){
    __syncthreads();
    if (threadIdx.x < s){
      smax[threadIdx.x] = IMAX(smax[threadIdx.x], smax[threadIdx.x+s]);
      smin[threadIdx.x] = IMIN(smin[threadIdx.x], smin[threadIdx.x+s]);}
    }
  if (!threadIdx.x){
    max[blockIdx.x] = smax[0];
    min[blockIdx.x] = smin[0];}
}


int main() {
    // data setup
    Cube *c = new Cube[ncubes];
    thrust::host_vector<size_t> csize(ncubes+1);
    csize[0] = 100;
    csize[1] = 1047;
    csize[2] = 5000;
    csize[3] = 0;  
    c[0].x = new dtype[csize[0]];
    c[1].x = new dtype[csize[1]];
    c[2].x = new dtype[csize[2]];
    size_t ctot = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < ncubes; i++) ctot+=csize[i];

    // method 1: thrust
    // concatenate
    thrust::host_vector<dtype> h_d(ctot);
    size_t start = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < ncubes; i++) {thrust::copy_n(c[i].x, csize[i], h_d.begin()+start); start += csize[i];}
    for (size_t i = 0; i < ctot; i++) h_d[i] = rand();
    thrust::device_vector<dtype> d_d = h_d;
    // build flag vector
    thrust::device_vector<int> d_f(d_d.size());
    thrust::host_vector<size_t> coff(csize.size());
    thrust::exclusive_scan(csize.begin(), csize.end(), coff.begin());
    thrust::device_vector<size_t> d_coff = coff;
    thrust::scatter(thrust::constant_iterator<int>(1), thrust::constant_iterator<int>(1)+ncubes, d_coff.begin(), d_f.begin());
    thrust::inclusive_scan(d_f.begin(), d_f.end(), d_f.begin());
    // min/max reduction
    thrust::device_vector<dtype> d_max(ncubes);
    thrust::device_vector<dtype> d_min(ncubes);
    thrust::reduce_by_key(d_f.begin(), d_f.end(), thrust::make_zip_iterator(thrust::make_tuple(d_d.begin(), d_d.begin())), thrust::make_discard_iterator(), thrust::make_zip_iterator(thrust::make_tuple(d_max.begin(), d_min.begin())), thrust::equal_to<int>(),  my_f());
    thrust::host_vector<dtype> h_max = d_max;
    thrust::host_vector<dtype> h_min = d_min;
    std::cout << "Thrust Maxima: " <<std::endl;
    thrust::copy_n(h_max.begin(), ncubes, std::ostream_iterator<dtype>(std::cout, ","));
    std::cout << std::endl << "Thrust Minima: " << std::endl;
    thrust::copy_n(h_min.begin(), ncubes, std::ostream_iterator<dtype>(std::cout, ","));
    std::cout << std::endl;

    // method 2: CUDA kernel (block reduce)
    block_segmented_minmax_reduce<<<ncubes, BS>>>(thrust::raw_pointer_cast(d_d.data()), thrust::raw_pointer_cast(d_max.data()), thrust::raw_pointer_cast(d_min.data()), thrust::raw_pointer_cast(d_coff.data()));
    thrust::copy_n(d_max.begin(), ncubes, h_max.begin());
    thrust::copy_n(d_min.begin(), ncubes, h_min.begin());
    std::cout << "CUDA Maxima: " <<std::endl;
    thrust::copy_n(h_max.begin(), ncubes, std::ostream_iterator<dtype>(std::cout, ","));
    std::cout << std::endl << "CUDA Minima: " << std::endl;
    thrust::copy_n(h_min.begin(), ncubes, std::ostream_iterator<dtype>(std::cout, ","));
    std::cout << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
$ nvcc -o t1535 t1535.cu
$ ./t1535
Thrust Maxima:
2145174067,2147469841,2146753918,
Thrust Minima:
35005211,2416949,100669,
CUDA Maxima:
2145174067,2147469841,2146753918,
CUDA Minima:
35005211,2416949,100669,
$
```

For a small number of `Cube` objects, the thrust method is likely to be faster.  It will tend to make better use of medium to large GPUs than the block method will.  For a large number of `Cube` objects, the block method should also be fairly efficient.

Comment: I just have one small question:
Do you think that the variants shown by you are also advantageous for very small but very many arrays (in pairs unequal size)?

Comment: For that I would probably use the thrust method.  If the arrays are large enough in number and also small enough, it might even be more efficient just to assign one thread per array, in a naive serial approach per-thread.  For instance if the average length of each array is one or 2 elements.