# How can I do segmented reduction using CUDA thrust?

Tags: c++, cuda, reduce, thrust

I want to store partial reduction results in an array.

Say I have `data[8] = {10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80}`.
And if I divide the `data` with the `chunk_size` of `2`, the chunks will be `{10,20}`, `{30,40}`, ... , `{70,80}`.

If I target the summation, the reduction in total will be `360` but I want to get an array of `partial_sums = {30,70,110,150}` which is storing the partial sum of each block.

So far, what I have in mind is to construct an iterator `strided_iterator`, that will access 0, 2, ... th index of `data[8] = {10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80}` and something like

```cpp
thrust::reduce(stride_iterator, stride_iterator + 2,
               partial_sums.begin(),
               thrust::plus<int>());
```

giving the desired result, but have no idea how could this be done efficiently.

For strided access, [`thrust/examples/strided_range.cu`](https://github.com/NVIDIA/thrust/blob/master/examples/strided_range.cu) has a solution but this seems to be not applicable to store segmented reductions.

Of course I can brutally do it with a loop like this,

```
for (int i = 0; i<4; i++) {
  partial_sums[i] = thrust::reduce(data+2*i, data+2*i+2, 0, thrust::plus<int>());
}
```

But this kind of practice is what CUDA thrust is trying to avoid as much as possible, right? Somehow I should be able to put it all in a single Thrust call.

Comment: The solution is `thrust::reduce_by_key`.

Comment: Although in this special case of a very small chunk size it might be more performant to zip together multiple strided ranges with different offsets and perform a transform for the summation.

Comment: Is chunk_size variable or always 2 ?

Comment: @paleonix, yes indeed this question was the exact duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42260493/reduce-multiple-blocks-of-equal-length-that-are-arranged-in-a-big-vector-using-c. I was not able to find it since I was searching via 'chunk', 'partial sum', and so on. I didn't know it was called 'segmented reduction'. Thanks for the keyword!

Comment: @AbatorAbetor, no the chunk size will be an order of 100~1000, and the number of chunks will be very large - at least an order of 10^4 and I will go as large as the GPU can stand w.r.t. the memory, and the practical computation time.

Comment: @AbatorAbetor, to be more specific, the chunk size will be an power of 2 (There is no big reason, naively expecting some speed up with all the memory access, coalescence stuff in CUDA), and at the current stage I suppose it would be sufficient by 256 and will be fixed in the compilation time defined in a header file. The number of chunks will be a variable (the number of particles in the computation domain), the value read from an input in runtime.

Comment: Due to the regularity you may find even better performance using [cuTENSOR](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cutensor/api/cutensor.html#cutensorreduction).

Comment: And if you want a C++ API, [MatX](https://nvidia.github.io/MatX/api/reduce.html) can be configured to use cuTENSOR, I think.

Comment: @paleonix, is cuTENSOR capable of 'partial' reduction in the segments? In fact, I should not use all the elements in the chunk for reduction. My chunk size is for the 'number of maximum possibly activated elements', and usually only first few elements will be activated (always [act, act, ..., act, de-act, ... , de-act], not [act, de-act, act, act, de-act ,...]). Thereby, I will have N sets of chunks of size K, and each chunks will have different number of activated elements M (M<K). M is different among all chunks. I want reductin with M, not K. Any suggestions will be very appreciated.

Comment: Well, then the problem is not regular anymore, so I think cuTENSOR wont be helpful. How do you know which elements are activated? Is there another array of flags or an array of `M`s?

Comment: @paleonix, I didn't intended it but I have an array in the exact same structure (N*K) in which every M has some finite positive integer values and de-activateds having -1.

Comment: Then you could just feed `reduce_by_key` with a transform iterator that gives zero for the deactivated ones. For performance, try to do kernel fusion where possible. E.g. the keys can be generated on the fly using a transform iterator on a counting iterator.

Comment: If you have answered your own question, the recommended way on SO to do that is to provide an answer, not edit the answer into your question.  Providing an answer to a question does not preclude the possibility of other answers.  Providing your solution as an answer makes it easier for others to find your solution method.

Comment: @RobertCrovella, sure I'll do it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the useful answer in
[Reduce multiple blocks of equal length that are arranged in a big vector Using CUDA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42260493/reduce-multiple-blocks-of-equal-length-that-are-arranged-in-a-big-vector-using-c), what I come up with so far is like follows.

In fact I wanted to get min or max values in each chunk.

```
using namespace thrust::placeholders;
int main(int argc, char **argv) {

  int N = atoi(argv[1]);
  int K = atoi(argv[2]);

  std::cout << "N " << N << " K " << K << std::endl;

  typedef int mytype;

  thrust::device_vector<mytype> data(N*K);
  thrust::device_vector<mytype> sums(N);

  thrust::sequence(data.begin(),data.end());

  // method 1
  thrust::reduce_by_key(thrust::device,
                        
  thrust::make_transform_iterator(thrust::counting_iterator<int>(0),  _1/K),
                        
  thrust::make_transform_iterator(thrust::counting_iterator<int>(N*K),_1/K),
                        data.begin(),
                        thrust::discard_iterator<int>(),
                        sums.begin(),
                        thrust::equal_to<int>(),
                        thrust::minimum<mytype>());

  // method 2 (bad)
  for (int i=0; i<N; i++) {
    int res = thrust::reduce(data.begin()+K*i, data.begin()+K*i+K,std::numeric_limits<mytype>::max(),thrust::minimum<mytype>());
  }

  // just print the first 10 results
  thrust::copy_n(sums.begin(),10,std::ostream_iterator<mytype>(std::cout, ","));
  std::cout << std::endl;

  return 0;
}
```

The results are shown below with the estimated runtime measured via sdkTimer. As can be seen, method 1 with `reduce_by_key` is much~ faster than the second one with for loop.

```
[sangjun@newmaster01 05_thrust]$ ./exe 1000 100
N 1000 K 100
 - Elapsed time: 0.00008 sec 
 - Elapsed time: 0.02266 sec 
0,100,200,300,400,500,600,700,800,900,
[sangjun@newmaster01 05_thrust]$ ./exe 1000 256
N 1000 K 256
 - Elapsed time: 0.00008 sec 
 - Elapsed time: 0.02084 sec 
0,256,512,768,1024,1280,1536,1792,2048,2304,
[sangjun@newmaster01 05_thrust]$ ./exe 100000 100
N 100000 K 100
 - Elapsed time: 0.00016 sec 
 - Elapsed time: 1.98978 sec 
0,100,200,300,400,500,600,700,800,900,
[sangjun@newmaster01 05_thrust]$ ./exe 100000 256
N 100000 K 256
 - Elapsed time: 0.00027 sec 
 - Elapsed time: 1.92896 sec 
0,256,512,768,1024,1280,1536,1792,2048,2304,
```